# GCMRegistrar.register doesn't work with wifi but does work with 3G (=UMTS?) and the emulator

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, android-wifi, 3g

I am working on an application with the notification and I use the GCMRegistar package.

When I test my app on a device by using the 3G, or when I test with the eclipse emulator, everything  is fine:

- the GCMBroadcastReceiver is called
- I receive the registerID from the GCM server
- The app receive the notification I sent from my server

But when I test my app on a device, connected with the wifi, nothing append after GCMRegistrar.register(...):
 - the GCMBroadcastReceiver is never called

Comment: Does it show any error in the LogCat. In the receiver try to print the messages that you are getting. Are you signed into google account on your phone? Also, you you might be behind a company firewall, if you are testing it using a company wifi.

Comment: I don't see any error in the log cat, the last output I can see is the call of GCMRegistar.register(..).

Comment: I am signed into a google account: the app work when I use the 3G. For the wifi, yes one of the two is the a company wifi, but the second one is my private wifi, and i have the same problem.

Comment: Try to download the FireBind app and test if your device has access to ports 5528-5230.

Comment: I try your app, and the result is: yes, in my office the 3 ports are blocked, I will ask to the IT office. I will all so try at home and give you the result.